# How to stop bash script after I click cancel on zenity progress window

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bin, zenity

I'm writting a script using bash script, in this code I have a process that runs together with a zenity progress bar. What is happening is that when I run it, and try to cancel the operation, it will keep running until I clic ctrl+c on the linux terminal, that is meant for cancelling the operation. Since I'm doing this for users that aren't programmers, this can't be the way to stop it.

This is the line I'm talking about:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH sOutputFile="$DESTINO.pdf" "$FILE" | zenity --progress --title="Processando" --auto-close --width=220 --text="Comprimindo PDF" --pulsate --percentage=0
```

I thought that I had the answer to solve this problem, because I used it in the other zenity windows like this one:

```
zenity --width=600 --height=300 --text-info --title="Test" --filename=/tmp/original.txt --editable > /tmp/changed.txt
case $? in
    1)
        exit
    ;;
esac
```

It works just fine, when I click cancel it stop the script, but when I tried to use it in the progress bar that runs with the gs command, it didn't work, the zenity window closed, but the script kept running.
This is how I tried solving it:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$DESTINO.pdf" "$FILE" | zenity --progress --title="Processando" --auto-close --width=220 --text="Comprimindo PDF" --pulsate --percentage=0 
case $? in
    1)
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

Anyone has ever had this problem? How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `--auto-kill` zenity option?

Comment: @Grobu Yes I have, but if I use the `--auto-kill` option, it continues running the script in the background when I click cancel, I would need a way to delete the file it is generating so it would really stop.

Comment: [yad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/) is a fork of `zenity`.  It has the option `--kill-parent=[SIGNAL] `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion (backslashes used for readability) :

```
#! /bin/sh

hup_handler()
  {
  kill -s KILL "$!"
  }

trap hup_handler HUP

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$DESTINO.pdf" "$FILE"   \
| zenity --progress --title="Processando" --auto-close --auto-kill \
         --width=220 --text="Comprimindo PDF" --pulsate --percentage=0 &
wait

echo 'end of script'
```

Apparently `zenity --progress --auto-kill` sends a HANGUP signal to the parent process when the "cancel" button is pressed. For some reason beyond my knowledge, that signal is processed only when the pipeline has completed unless you place it in the background with `&`.

If you want to delete the file when the user clicks on the "cancel" button, you could add `rm -f "$DESTINO.pdf"` in the `hup_handler` function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tested it, it closes zenity and frees the terminal, but it keeps running the gs command and creating the PDF file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will test it again

Comment: It's alright, thanks for the help. I have a function open() after the gs and zenity command, that opens the folder where the PDF is, and it is still running even after I exited the script for some reason, that's how I'm testing it .

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of my friend @Grobu, I made some changes and got to this result that solved my problem, it stops gs and removes the created PDF from the file, thank you very much!

```
#!/bin/bash

hup_handler()
{
rm -f "$DESTINO.pdf"
kill 0
}

trap hup_handler HUP

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$DESTINO.pdf" "$FILE" | zenity --progress --title="Processando" --auto-close --auto-kill --width=220 --text="Comprimindo PDF" --pulsate --percentage=0 &
wait
```